# Java Runtime Error SIGBUS iText

Tags: java, pdf, runtime-error, itext

I'm trying to sign using iText 5.5.0 with the documentation example:

```
private static void pdfSign(String srcFile, String dstFile) throws Exception

    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", "BC");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(PFX_ROUTE), PFX_PASSPHRASE);
    String alias = (String)ks.aliases().nextElement();
    PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey)ks.getKey(alias, KEY_PASSPHRASE);
    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(alias);
    // reader and stamper
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(srcFile);
    PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, new FileOutputStream(dstFile), '\0');
    // appearance
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
    appearance.setVisibleSignature(SIGNFIELD_NAME);
    appearance.setReason("Test");
    appearance.setLocation("TestLocation");


    ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA-1", "BC");
    ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

I am getting the following error.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x00007fff943f8be0, pid=602, tid=6403
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsystem_platform.dylib+0x3be0]  _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown+0xe0
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit                 -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/twofaz/Documents/Development/Clarice/Clarice.iText5/hs_err_pid602.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

My java version is:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

I am using Netbeans IDE 7.4 and the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files substituted in my /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security path.

I already tried the: "ulimit -c unlimited" command from my terminal.

Comment: Please show the contents of `hs_err_pid602.log`.

Comment: Added the contents here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20061552/hs_err_pid602.log

Comment: Hhmmm, `sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory` often seems to be involved in interesting JVM crashes. You might want to try a different `PdfReader` constructor, e.g. first reading the file into memory and then using the constructor with a `byte[]` argument.

Comment: Did try it that way, still same error.

Comment: Alternatively, have you tried a different jvm version? As iTextin your use case does only use standard api calls, this most likely is a Java error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it was, I tried my code on another environment and it gave me a BouncyCastle Exception. I changed the BC JAR to the 1.48 version and it worked correctly on my Windows Environment. On my Unix environment I am having problems to save the file.

Thanks to all